# Same WebView on every view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Basically i have a `WebView` on `SecondViewController` and I wish for the `WebView` to be visible on every view like a tab bar and fully controllable on each view.

Please note the `WebView` will be on a webpage with a online slideshow so I cannot simply reload on each view

Also in the `SecondViewController` I have

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)YouTubePlayer {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just set up a singleton UIWebView and add it to each view-controller-view when that view controller is about to become visible.  Here's one way to do it:

```
//.h

@interface SharedWebView : UIWebView
{
}

+ (SharedWebView*) shared;

@end

//.m

SharedWebView* g_sharedWebView;

@implementation SharedWebView


+ (SharedWebView*) shared 
{
    if ( g_sharedWebView == nil )
    {
        g_sharedWebView = [[SharedWebView alloc] init];

        // ... any other intialization you want to do
    }

    return g_sharedWebView;
}

@end


// in your view controller(s)

@property (readonly) UIWebView* webView

- (UIWebView*) webView
{
    return [SharedWebView shared];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    [self.view addSubview: self.webView ];
    self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300);

    // want to re-set the delegate?
    // self.webView.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: i am getting an error with the 

- (UIWebView*) webView
{
    return [SharedWebView shared];
}


in .h

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest adding the `webView` on you window after the you add the `tabbarcontroller.view` just like:

```
[window addSubview:tabbarController.view];
[window addSubview:webview];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and initially make don't make it visible. You should handle all the webview related methods in the app delegate. Now whenever you don't need it you can hide it by calling the methods your wrote in app delegate from your view controllers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to just make all of your view controllers aware of this extra view (make the view available through a singleton PinnedViewController or whatever). During each view controller's `-viewWillAppear`, just do this:

```
[self addSubview:[[PinnedViewController sharedController] view]];
```

This will move the view to whoever is currently active (making a view your subview automatically removes you from your old hierarchy).

If that is cumbersome or otherwise unworkable, there are two other options. First, you can subclass `UITabViewController` (I assume that's what you're using here from your question), and inject your extra view (resizing the content view to make room). This is undocumented and unsupported, so take heed. But it's not incredibly difficult if you don't do too many other fancy tricks.

The other tricky solution is to create a second `UIWindow` that you float over the main `UIWindow` (or resize the main `UIWindow` to make room for it). This is only semi-documented and is also not really supported. But this approach can work if you're trying to put the extra view below the tabbar for instance.

But if your system is simple enough, I recommend just letting your view controllers all manage the pinned view manually. You'll save a lot of code spelunking that way, and you won't have to rely on any undocumented internal view hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you try to put views on top of this view but not modal. There was this blog entry I once saw that described how you would do something like this. I think it should apply also for your case: [semi-modal-transparent-dialogs-on-the-iphone](http://ramin.firoozye.com/2009/09/29/semi-modal-transparent-dialogs-on-the-iphone/)

Comment: I am using tabs on the view if this makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

In iOS UIViewControllers are expected to manage an entire "screen" worth of content so it's not normal to try to share a single view across many view controllers. Trying to have UIViewControllers whose views only manage part of their window is problematic and will result in unexpected behavior as UIKit will not send messages like -viewWillAppear to all view controllers with visible views. Instead you would normally create a single UIViewController whose view includes that web view and whatever other views compose your tab like interface.
Alternately you could have a hierarchy of many view controllers and add a single web view as a subview of all of them. You would then pull your web view delegate behavior out into some non-UIViewController controller class to manage the behavior of the web view.

Answer (score 0):

You can have all your views take up a portion of the screen and have your `UIWebView` take up the rest. The logic for switching between the other views should remain the same.

For example, in your `viewDidLoad` method for your `UIViewController`s, you could have something like:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 380);
```

And in your (say) `AppDelegate`, you would have your normal call to show the main `UIViewController` (in your case, it sounds like a `UITabBarController`?) and also have a call to add the `UIWebView`. Say, something like:

```
myWebView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
```

The view controllers and `UIWebView` would be independent of each other.

You see this pattern, I believe, with apps that have iAds. I've done something just like this with one of my free apps.

Hope this helps!

Comment: A UIViewController's root view (the one exposed as the 'view' property) is expected to fill the window and auto-resize. Creating a controller with a view which fills only part of the screen is problematic and can result in unexpected behavior when UIKit fails to send your controller normal view controller lifecycle messages.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same effect by simply adding it to the navigationController itself(if you don't have one then just add it).
works great for me in one of my apps.

Answer (score -1):

Could you not use two webviews on your application and simply change the uppermost webview with your more dynamic content?