# Question on View Controller's view

Tags: objective-c

When we access View Controller's view property, does it always represent the entire screen or it can be partial?

Indirectly speaking, does a View Controller can have multiple view properties ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

donkim is right but don't take my word for it ;)

See this post by Rincewind: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/81930 and any number of older comments from other Apple employees on their forums.

> If I'm understanding what you are
>   saying, you've created another view
>   controller (BlueViewController) and
>   added its view as a subview of another
>   view controller? If so, then this is
>   covered by the docs – specifically to
>   say not to do that because it is not
>   supported.
>   A view controller is
>   meant to manage an entire screen's
>   worth of content. If you want to
>   subdivide your content further, then
>   it is recommended that you use objects
>   other than subclasses of a
>   UIViewController to manage those
>   subregions and manage those objects
>   with a UIViewController subclass.

In addition we have the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which states:

> You use each instance of UIViewController to manage a view hierarchy. A typical view hierarchy consists of a root view—a reference to which is available in the view property of this class—and usually one or more subviews presenting the actual content. On iPhone and iPod touch, the root view typically fills the entire screen but on iPad this view may fill only part of the screen. In both cases, the view controller is responsible for managing the entire view hierarchy, including all subviews.

and also the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW1):

> The root view acts as the container for all other views associated with your view controller. You typically define the frame for this view to match the size of the application window, which itself should fill the screen. However, the view controller also adjusts the frame size as needed to accommodate the presence of assorted views, such as the system status bar, a navigation bar, or a tab bar.

Unfortunately none of those are as explicit as I would like about *why* UIViewController makes these assumptions and when it might be safe to break them. From what I can tell without access to UIKit code somewhere UIKit assumes a single view controller will be responsible for a given screen worth of content. In some cases it therefore sends messages like -viewWillAppear: or -didRecieveMemoryWarning to only one (or maybe only some) view controllers if you have multiple view controllers visible in a single window. It should be possible to demonstrate this in at least a couple of different ways though I haven't tested all of these recently so I'm going off of other user's reported problems.
Nested view controllers will not receive -didReceiveMemoryWarning
Multiple view controller's view will not be rotated if rotation occurs while a modal view controller is presented and the modal is then dismissed.
View controllers' views are sometimes expected to fill the window and be opaque so the content drawn in regions of the window they do not cover can be undefined. Trying to present a modal view controller which did not fill the screen would not render underlying views, at least in iOS 3.1.x or whatever the last version I tried was.

---

To try to directly answer hmthur's question. A UIViewController should have a single root view (its 'view' property) which fills the window and which can handle being resized to fit status bars, tab bars, and so on. That controller may have any number of sub views of that root view and properties which reference those sub views.

---

As a further update consider this thread on "[Creating container UIViewController subclasses?](https://devforums.apple.com/message/365171#365171)" on the Apple developer forums (discussing setting `parentViewController` in order to build custom container view controllers).

> All UIKit ivars are considered private and their direct access is unsupported, including access through setValue:forKey:. The method that sets this ivar is also private.
>
> As for this ivar [parentViewController], I will warn you that its behavior is likely to change.
>
> Unfortunately I don't have any good suggestions for alternatives, though for what it's worth we do recognize the difficulty in creating container view controllers.

Comment: I should probably add that with the iPad and OS 4.2 we're seeing more support for view controllers which don't necessarily fill the window and so you might not have as many problems now. Unfortunately Apple has yet to provide a supported way for us to write our own container view controllers (like UINavigationController, UITabBarController, or UISplitViewController) so nesting view controllers remains tricky (no public API for setting parentViewController as one example).

Comment: +1 for all the great sources. Though I'd argue that the first one from the Apple employee doesn't support what you say -- he/she says not to add a view controller's `view` to another view controller's `view` and that a view controller is meant to manage an entire screen's worth of content, which may or may not be filled by the view controller's `view` (whew, that's quite a mouthful :)

Comment: And Jonah, where have I heard of Carbon Five..? I feel I've heard of it in the news recently..? :)

Comment: I think that stating that a view controller is responsible for the entire screen suggests that the window should not contain views not owned by the view controller but I agree that's not explicitly stated.

I can't say where you might have heard of Carbon Five but I'm glad you have.

Comment: You have to ask, though, just what is "not supported" about it.   It is clearly possible to write custom container UIViewController subclasses, I have a whole large app heavily based around modular and nested UIViewControllers, because UINavigationController and UITabbarController just don't have the look and interaction I needed for my app.    If "not supported" means "you have to pass down Did/Will Appear/Disapper manually", then that's no big deal.   The only thing I found that didn't work is presenting a modal view controller from a non-full-screen VC, so I just present from the root vc.

Comment: @Bogatyr by "not supported" I mean that you are outside the constraints of the public API for UIViewController and as a result the behavior you rely on is likely to change without warning and differ between iOS point releases. In addition it means that you are creating classes which advertise themselves as acting as UIViewControllers but don't necessarily behave reliably which is a pain if anyone else ever uses those classes. I think controllers with a protocol implementing viewWill/Did(Dis)appear make lots of sense, just don't pretend that they are UIViewControllers.

Comment: Well, whatever the ultimate truth is, this "one full screen at a time" only is a terrible software organization limitation for serious apps with many reusable components, and apps that don't fit the narrow canned meta-VC choices provided.

Comment: I've tried to cover this in more detail here: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/

Answer (score 0):

According to Jonah in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454289/same-webview-on-every-view/4576275#4576275), a view in a `UIViewController` should be assumed to fill up the entire screen. I've written apps that have a view of a `UIViewController` not take the entire screen and it's worked great for me.

For your second question, any `UIView` can add other `UIView`s via the `addSubview:` method. So yes, in a sense, there can be multiple views in the `UIViewController` (though there will only be the one `view` property).