# Potential leak of an object allocated - UIViewController

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiview, uiviewcontroller

My app is View based application.
I got 3 viewcontrollers. (main,sub,detail)
each viewcontroller has one UIView.
in MainViewcontroller, there's a button to launch subView.
the method is as below.

> -(IBAction) LaunchSubView: (id)sender {

```
subViewcontroller *viewController = [[subViewcontroller alloc] init];

UIView *currentView = self.view;
[UIView transitionFromView:currentView 
                    toView:viewController.view 
                  duration:0.5 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft   
                completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

}

While i try build and analyze, I got this warning.
**Potential leak of an object allocated on line 54 and stored into 'viewController'**
i tried [viewController release] after transitionFromView method and subViewcontroller *viewController = [[[subViewcontroller alloc] init] autorelease]; both ways cause the app crash. any idea what am i suppose to do? thanks in advance for any kind help. =)

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running? I tried to reproduce the problem without success.

Comment: hi.. i'm running Version 3.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` is not the right method to use. You should probably be using `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

If you read the documentation for `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` it explains:

> This method modifies the views in their view hierarchy only. It does not modify your application’s view controllers in any way. For example, if you use this method to change the root view displayed by a view controller, it is your responsibility to update the view controller appropriately to handle the change."

Comment: Exactly, in addition you are expected not to nest UIViewController's views like that. It would however be fine to have two views which are subviews of a single UIViewController's root view and use `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` to switch between them.

Comment: @Jonah Why do you say we're not expected to next UIViewControllers like that? I've done this a few times in my app where I want to keep my code modular and not have everything lumped up all into one or two single view controllers?

Comment: @Straddle take a look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591586/question-on-view-controllers-view/4591746#4591746 Splitting up your code into multiple controllers is good but they shouldn't all necessarily inherit from UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

try using

`subViewcontroller *viewController = [[subViewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"name of you nib file" bundle:@"if you have a bundle otherwise nil"]`

and also release the viewController object before the end of the method
like this

`[subViewcontroller release];`

Comment: sorry man i am quite used to the auto completion of the xcode so i dont remember all the method names. Thanks by the way

Comment: hi.. once i release the viewcontroller, the app crashed. as long as I don't release it, the app is working fine. but I got potential leaks. =(

Comment: Yes i think you are not retaining the objects in other view controller than. Are you sure that you are setting property for all the objects in another view